# Which Latin declension is most common?

Tags: morphology, declension, statistics

Does anyone know the rough proportions of Latin words that fall into each of the five declensions? Which is most common? Which is least common?

Comment: The percentages of the two answers come from different sources, one from a corpus and one from a dictionary. A corpus is more descriptive of actual use, but the question didn't specify what was meant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this study](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4489422?seq=1), the distribution is as follows:

- 1st declension 21.6%
- 2nd declension 23.7%
- 3rd declension 52.6%
- 4th declension 1.4%
- 5th declension 0.7%

(["Development of Gender Classifications: Modeling the Historical Change from Latin to French,"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4489422?seq=1) by Maria Polinsky and Ezra Van Everbroeck Language Vol. 79, No. 2, Jun., 2003, Table 2, pg. 362)

Comment: I wonder if the other stats are based on frequency of occurrence.  5th declension is tiny in terms of lexis, but *dies* and *res* are pretty commonly used words.

Comment: @CMonsour. According to the article, the data comes from two sources: another study, which is ["The frequency of Latin words and their endings,"](https://archive.org/details/PAULB.DIEDERICHLATINWORDFREQUENCY/page/n24/mode/2up) Diederich, 1939; and a random sampling of 1500 nouns from classical Latin texts.

Answer (score 5):

Difficult to verify this research but, according to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/3sfl77/distribution_of_nouns_across_declensions/), the distribution over *An Elementary Latin Dictionary* (Lewis) would be:

- 1st declension 19.14% (1248)
- 2nd declension 31.28% (2039)
- 3rd declension 45.93% (2994)
- 4th declension 3.59% (234)
- 5th declension 0.06% (4)